# Given that $\theta=45°$, find $\angle AOC$.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, solid-geometry

[image]
I only know that $AB=OB$, and that the two right triangles $AOC$ and $AOB$ share a same line $OA$. Does $\angle BOC=45°$ hint something?
The answer from the book is $60°$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it means $AB\perp(OBC)$, otherwise it's undefined.

The hint:

Prove that $$\measuredangle OCB=90^{\circ}.$$

Indeed, $AB\perp(OBC)$, which says $AB$ is perpendicular to any line in the plane,

which says $AB\perp OC$.

Now, we see that $$OC\perp AB$$ and from the given
$$OC\perp AC.$$
Also, $$AC\cap AB=\{A\}.$$
Thus, $$OC\perp(ABC)$$ and from here $$OC\perp BC.$$

From here: let $AB=a$.

Thus, $$\tan\measuredangle AOC=\frac{AC}{OC}=\frac{a\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}}{\frac{a}{\sqrt2}}=\sqrt3.$$

Comment: Is $\angle OCB=90°$ only when $\angle BOC=45°$ or are $BC$ and $OC$ always perpendicular? From the answer I could tell that but I can't prove it

Comment: @T. Joel It works because $AB\perp(OBC)$ and $OC\perp AC$. We have no here any relation with $45^{\circ}.$

Comment: I'm sorry but could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @T. Joel I added something. See now.

Comment: Is $(AB)$ perpendicular to all the plane? Or just to $(OB)$?

Comment: @Fareed AF By definition $l\perp\pi$ it's for any $a\subset\pi$ we have $l\perp a$. From the context $AB\perp(OBC),$ otherwise it's undefined. Thank you for your point!

Comment: If $AB\not \perp (OBC)$ why is it undefined? Can't it have another solution?

Comment: @Fareed AF If so, we can assume that $A\in(OBC)$ for example, which gives another solutions.